# can I limit records retrieved in ColdFusion cffile action = read?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a file which I want to retrieve with a cffile action = read command.  However, I would like to give the user the option of only retrieving a small number of lines.  The file could be quite large, and might take a very long time to load.  Meanwhile the user may only need to know whether he wants to delete it, and a page or two may be quite enough.  Does ColdFusion offer any way to limit the output of this command?  Or can anyone suggest another approach to this problem?

Comment: What are the details of the file?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it's a text file?  If so, use the `<cfloop file="" and line="">` like so and read line-by-line in a loop and stop after some number of lines.

> ```
> <cfset lineCount = 0>
> <cfloop file="c:\temp\simplefile.txt" index="line"> 
>     <cfoutput>#line#</cfoutput><br> 
>     <cfset lineCount++>
>     <cfif lineCount EQ 10>
>         <cfbreak>
>     </cfif>
> </cfloop>
> ```

OR:

> To read a specified number of characters from a text file during each
>   iteration of the loop, use the tag as follows:
>
> ```
> <cfloop file="c:\temp\simplefile.txt" index="chars" characters="12">  
>     <cfoutput>#chars#</cfoutput><br>
> </cfloop>
> ```

Quote from: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-71a7.html

Comment: looks promising -- will try it as soon as I can get back to that part of the project ...

Comment: Well, it didn't work out too well.  This approach produces the lines in the file.  However, some of that is formatting, which has to be invoked by HTML.  The loop around the file approach may be a basis for another way to do this.  So thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If the content is HTML, and you just want to show first few lines of it, you need to parse it by `jSoup` and extract the text out of it.  But then you pretty much need to read the whole file before you can parse by `jSoup`.

Comment: Hi Henry,  I tried again using the character option, and it worked quite well  - gave me the output of the file. It also included a piece of one line that was code, not output.  Can't understand that, but will fool around with it.